# Set Camera Depth of Field so that the character is not blurry, but the scene behind it is

Tags: camera, depth-of-field

I set a scene in evee and I really like the effect of the Camera Depth of field. In this scene I have a character right in foreground. The effect of the camera blurs it way too much. Is there something I can do to maintain the effect on the scene but not on the character?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe render just the bakground with one camera settings, then just character with other settings and then join two renders in Gimp.

Answer (score 1):

Depth of field is the area in which elements are acceptably in focus. Objects closer of further away from that area will be progressively blurry.

[image]
Image from https://expertphotography.com/understanding-depth-of-field-photography/

By changing the focus and the $f$ stop (iris) on the camera, you can determine where objects are in focus and when they are not. The wider (lower value) on the $f$ stop, focus will be more critical. As you close (higher value) the iris to a higher $f$ stop more of the scene (in front and behind the object) will be in focus, or less blurry.

Here's an example from [wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field)

[image]

Play with the values for focus and $f$ stop, until you find the point where you get the results you are after.

Answer (score 0):

In the camera menu under depth of field, you can set the focus object to the character in order to keep the character in focus. Note that it will focus on the origin of the character object (the small orange dot that appears when you select the object in object mode). If the dot is not centered on the object, you can center it by clicking Object > Set Origin > Origin to Center of Mass (Volume).

You can also manually change the focus distance under the depth of field menu. When changing the focus distance, changing the F-Stop might also be needed to get the same amount of bokeh for the background as before.